# Como converte esse Sql para entity framework?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Estou com dificuldade para passar esse sql para o `Entity Framework` estou usando o mvc 4.

```
select pc.Nome, pc.Endereco, pc.Bairro, pc.Numero, 
    pc.Telefone, pc.Email, ma.descricao
    from PontoDeColeta pc
    Inner join Material ma on(pc.IDMaterial = ma.IDMaterial)
    inner join Material on (ma.Descricao like '%variavel%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não deu muito detalhe do modelo, mas sua query em linq ficaria assim.

```
var PontoDeColeta_Material = (from t1 in Context.PontoDeColeta
                              join t3 in Context.Material on t1.IDMaterial equals t3.IDMaterial
                              where SqlMethods.Like(t3.Descricao, "%" + "variavel" + "%")
                              select new
                              {
                                  t1.Nome,
                                  t1.Endereco,
                                  t1.Bairro,
                                  t1.Numero,
                                  t1.Telefone,
                                  t1.Email,
                                  t3.descricao,
                              }).Tolist();
```

Eu não vejo motivo algum para você esta fazendo 2 join com a mesma tabela e não utilizado os dados das duas, acho que um Where no lugar do ultimo join seria o que você precisava.